# The drag event not firing in Firefox or IE

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

In Chrome the drag event is fired and logged to the console.
In Firefox and IE, it does not.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
  #d {
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="d" draggable="true"></div>

<script>
    d = document.getElementById('d');
    d.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
      console.log("dragstart:", e);
    });
    d.addEventListener('drag', function(e){
      console.log("drag:", e);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Fiddle version: http://jsfiddle.net/korimako/e1wqafyr

How do I set up a div to dispatch drag events and listen for them properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firefox requires that [`dataTransfer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) is set before the drag event is fired

```
d = document.getElementById('d');

d.addEventListener('drag', function(e){
    console.log("drag:", e)
});

d.addEventListener('dragstart', function(e){
    e.dataTransfer.setData('application/node type', this);
    console.log("dragstart:", e)
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/e1wqafyr/2/)

See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Recommended_Drag_Types) for drag types

Comment: This doesn't work when the draggable element is inside anchor element.

Answer (score 0):

As an update to @quarky's 2018 comment, as of 10 Jan 2023, it is still the case that in Firefox (108.0.1) the dragstart() event does not fire if the draggable element is inside an anchor element.

In my case my draggable element was an < img > and I worked around it by removing the enclosing < a href > and using an onclick("window.open(URL, '_blank')") on the < img >.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).